# Airflow - Patching a function during initialization

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, python-dataclasses

I have an airflow project with running dags.

In my Python code, I have a [dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) that includes a defaultdict. when I'm trying to use the [asdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.asdict) method, I get an exception(The exception details are included in the bug descrption below).

It appears that this is an open bug: https://bugs.python.org/issue35540.

As a solution, I wrote a patching function that replaces the asdict function.
I'm trying to find a place where I can hook this change during airflow initializtion(before my dags will run):

```
import copy
from collections import defaultdict
from dataclasses import _is_dataclass_instance, fields, asdict


def my_asdict(obj, dict_factory=dict):
    if _is_dataclass_instance(obj):
        result = []
        for f in fields(obj):
            value = my_asdict(getattr(obj, f.name), dict_factory)
            result.append((f.name, value))
        return dict_factory(result)
    elif isinstance(obj, (list, tuple)):
        return type(obj)(my_asdict(v, dict_factory) for v in obj)
    elif isinstance(obj, defaultdict):
        # This is the patch          
        obj = dict(obj)
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        return type(obj)((my_asdict(k, dict_factory), my_asdict(v, dict_factory))
                         for k, v in obj.items())
    else:
        return copy.deepcopy(obj)


asdict = my_asdict
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: This question miss the context of what is the issue you have with Airflow? If you monkey patched the function then what is the problem? Please share a minimal reproduce example of your DAG and what exactly is failing/not working.

Comment: @Elad - the issue is described in the link to the python bug. It is NOT airflow issue. It is a dataclass issue.

Comment: @balderman I'm aware but the Op mentioned that the issue is how to utalize the code created to overcome the bug with the DAGs in Airflow. Which is why I'm asking to see the Airflow DAG code as the question is `trying to find a place where I can hook this change during airflow initializtion(before my dags will run)` yet it's not clear to me why this is needed so i asked to see the code that integrates the DAG with the patch presented in the question and what traceback it produce on Airflow. Airflow is orchestration. if the op has workaround it should work seamlessly with Airflow.

Comment: As far as I understand the Op is using dataclass and is interested in patching 'asdict' because of the bug that was mentioned. The Op is looking for a location where the patch can be applied during airflow init. Are you interested in seeing the actual exception that is caused by the bug?  Please explain what is missing.

Comment: @balderman Ah got it now. I thought there is an issue with a specific process that tries to use the workaround but it seems that the issue is that the op wants all usages of the bugged function will be rerouted to the modified one - if so indeed this is not something to be solved on Airflow level.

Comment: @Elad. Is there a hook  that can be called during airflow startup? I think this is the direction the Op is looking for.

Comment: I'm not sure if this runs early enough for your use case, but take a look at [Cluster Policies](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/administration-and-deployment/cluster-policies.html) to patch DAGs/Tasks/Task Instances.

Answer (score 2):

I think I am on the same scenario as you, I need to patch an operator for running it on development like a dummy operator instead of actually doing something and I was searching where to patch it, since all the Airflow code starts at the airflow cli, I just patched the airflow entrypoint file and it worked like a charm

Since I am using airflow on docker the entrypoint file is on `/home/airflow/.local/bin/airflow`
and I just changed the file to

```py
#!/usr/local/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys
from airflow.__main__ import main

# patch
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.glue_crawler import GlueCrawlerOperator

def dummy(*args, **kwargs):
    pass

GlueCrawlerOperator.execute = dummy


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).